# Sketch a graph of the following function - how to?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

In the image you have the function and its graph. I don't know how is the graph gotten?
I calculated that the zeros are:
   $ x = 0, x = -3$
and the function isn't defined for:
  $ x = 4, x = -2$.

But in the solution I see whole three curves for that method, how do I get them? And the asymptote, from where do I get that?

Comment: Here is the correct graph: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/562985grzezggz.png (Blue parts: Real Parts - Orange pars: Imaginary parts)

Comment: @Adobe How did you get it?

Comment: @dfgjfghk Copy Paste all of this into your browser: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\sqrt{\frac{x^3+%2B+3x^2}{x+^2+-+2x+-+8}}

Comment: @Adobe, you are linking to an image of the function, interpreted as having **complex** values.  The OP can safely ignore the plot of the *imaginary* part of the function (the red curve in Alpha).

Comment: @SammyBlack He can deactivate it.

Comment: The image in the original post is great, provided that you know how to interpret the different parts of it.  For instance, the diagonal black line is the *asymptote* of the rational function $f(x)$, but it is not part of the graph of the function!

Comment: Here is the graph for the real part only: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/552442grzezggz.png

Comment: Yes, that is **a** graph of the function, which does not show the important features of the function as well as the image originally posted!

Comment: @SammyBlack What about this one? http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/262453graph20131020051633.png

Answer (score 1):

First, let's talk about the rational function
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^3 + 3x^2}{x^2 - 2x - 8} = \frac{x^2(x + 3)}{(x + 2)(x - 4)}.
$$
It has

- vertical asymptotes at $x = -2$ and $x = 4$ (these are the gaps in
  the domain that you mention),
- zero at $x = 0$ (of multiplicity 2, meaning that locally the graph looks like a parabola)
- zero at $x = -3$
- slant asymptote of $y = x + 5$.

Since there are two real numbers where the function is undefined, the graph is made of three disconnected curves:  on the intervals $(-\infty, -2)$, $(-2, 4)$, and $(4, \infty)$.  You have a pretty good sketch of $y = f(x)$ in black.

---

If $g(u) = \sqrt{u}$, then you are interested in the composition
$$
(g \circ f)(x) = g \big( f(x) \big) = \sqrt{\frac{x^3 + 3x^2}{x^2 - 2x - 8}}.
$$
What is the effect of the square root?  First of all, we only consider real square roots of non-negative numbers, so the composite function $g \circ f$ is only defined where $f(x) \ge 0$, specifically on the intervals $[-3, -2)$ and $(4, \infty)$ and, curiously, at the single point $x = 0$.

As far as the shape of your red curve goes, we can observe the qualitative phenomenon that square roots tend to push positive numbers towards $1$.  When the black curve is below $y = 1$, then the corresponding points on the red curve are above it.  When the black curve is above $y = 1$, then the corresponding points on the red curve are below it.

Regarding the end behavior of $g \circ f$ (what happens as $x \to \infty$), it approaches the curve $y = \sqrt{x + 5}$ asymptotically, as you can see in this image.

[image: Plot of function and asymptotic curve.]

Comment: What software did you use to draw the graph?

Comment: Mathematica 8 (Wolfram's flagship product that runs the back-end of the Alpha site).

Comment: How did you get the asymptote, x+5?

Comment: Polynomial long division.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division